# What flutter project should I create for my goals?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am looking to create applications for mobile on iOS and android, I was wondering what type of flutter project I should choose to suit this goal?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go with `flutter application`. It will generate `main.dart` as sample application file inside the `lib` folder. you can customize that code easily.

Answer (score 0):

In that choose **flutter application** and your project will create. In that you can see the android, ios, lib and asset folder.

- In lib folder you can see the **main.dart**, this the mail file for start project.
- Assets folder you can use for show the images.
- Android and ios folder for particular build.